# What is the smallest connected closed set?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

X is connected compact space , A is closed subset of X.

Is there the set B such that has the following property:

1) B is  connected  closed set  contaning A
2) When C is proper subset of B and connected closed set, then C must not contain A

??

I think  there is definition  for such B

Thank you for any help

Comment: This question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285686/minimal-connected-set-containing-a-closed-connected-set-in-a-compact-space?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a set $B$ is not necessarily a smallest one.

Take for example the set $A$ as two disjoint closed disks in $[0,1]^2$. If we let $B$ be a set that contains $A$ and any line (that does not cross itself) connecting the disks in $A$, then this is an example of a minimal set as you describe. However, clearly we can take different lines to get different sets $B$.

---

If $X$ is Hausdorff, you can prove the existence of such a set. If $X$ is Hausdorff, we can use that the [intersection of a chain of compact connected sets is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238027/in-a-hausdorff-space-the-intersection-of-a-chain-of-compact-connected-subspaces)

There always exists such a set $B$, since $X$ is connected. We can order closed connected subsets of $X$ that contain $A$ by inclusion, then every chain of such subsets has a lower bound, as the intersection of the chain will be closed, connected and contain $A$. The existence of $B$ is therefore guaranteed by Zorn's lemma.

---

A counterexample of a non-Hausdorff space is the line with two origins. If we let $A$ consist of these two origins, then taking intervals $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon>0$ contains $A$, but the intersection of all such intervals only contains $A$ and is not connected.

Comment: The intersection of two connected sets needs not to be connected. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582608/must-the-intersection-of-connected-sets-be-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I'm not stating that the intersection of connected sets is connected, I'm stating that the intersection of a chain of *inclusions* is connected.

Comment: You are right, my bad.

Comment: You need an Hausdorff compact space for your argument to work, and this requires a proof. If the space is compact, but not Hausdorff, this is no longer true. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29231/arbitrary-intersection-of-closed-connected-subsets-of-a-compact-space-connected).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I see now... I'll edit my answer accordingly