# Looking for a counter example for non-connected intersection of descending chain of closed connected sets

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\left\{ Y_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{\infty}$
 be a descending chain of closed connected subsets of $X$. I know from reading elsewhere that ${\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}Y_{i}}$ is not necessarily a connected subspace of $X$   but I have no counter example and I haven't managed to come up with one. 
There is a counter example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29231/arbitrary-intersection-of-closed-connected-subsets-of-a-compact-space-connected) to the same question while also assuming $X$ is compact. However, it uses the quotient topology which I haven't studied about so I would prefer a different counterexample that does not use the quotient topology.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: corrected title to fit the post regarding the sets being closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29231/arbitrary-intersection-of-closed-connected-subsets-of-a-compact-space-connected) can also be said without the quotient:

Let $X:=[-1,1]\cup\{0'\}$ where $0'$ is a new, fictive element, playing the role of a *second origin*, and define the topology on $[-1,1]$ as usual, and let $(-a,b)\setminus\{0\}\cup\{0'\}$ be a base for open neighborhoods of $0'$.

Now consider $Y_n:=[-1/n,1/n]\cup\{0'\}$.

Comment: Ah this is a nice representation for the topology with two origins. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

In $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ take two disjoint infinite lines $L_{1},L_{2}$ connected by vertical lines $B_{1},...$ (like a ladder). Then define 
$$A_{n}=L_{1}\cup L_{2}\cup \bigcup_{k\geq n}B_{k}.$$

These form a descending chain and their intersection will be $L_{1}\cup L_{2}$.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following sets:
$$Y_i = \bigg([-2,2]\times\mathbb{R}\bigg) - \bigg((-1,1)\times(-i,i)\bigg).$$

That is, $Y_i$ is a closed infinite strip with successively larger open boxes removed. The intersection 
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty Y_i = ([-2,-1]\cup[1,2])\times\mathbb{R}$$
is disconnected, but each $Y_i$ is closed and connected.

Comment: It took me a couple of minute to realise that you we removing a subset of the open disk, not taking a product of the punctured open disk (there really should be some parentheses here). Given that, are the sets you describe not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: The example then no longer satisfies the OP's condition.

Comment: @DanielRust: Same idea: Remove a "fattened interval" $(-1/2,1/2) \times (-1+1/i, 1-1/i)$ from $[-1,1]^2$.

Comment: On the same link to the referred question they prove that no counterexample can be found in *normal* spaces.

Comment: @Martin this still doesn't seem to satisfy the OP's requirement (unless i'm missing something).

Comment: @DanielRust: It's a descending chain of closed connected sets, so what's missing?

Comment: Like Berci said in the link I gave they prove that the claim is true in a compact hausdorff space (which is also a normal space) and thus true in every metric space. So no subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (with metric topology) is going to work as a counter example.

Comment: @Martin The OP wants their intersection to be not connected.

Comment: @Serpahimz: I don't follow your deduction from compact to normal to metric. Replace the closed square $[-1,1]^2$ by the open square $(-1,1)^2$ and remove $(-1/2,1/2) \times (-1+1/i, 1-1/i)$ in my previous example. Then the intersection is $((-1,-1/2] \cup [1/2,1)) \times (-1,1)$ which is manifestly disconnected.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry I got things a bit mixed up indeed. 
The claim is true in a compact Hausdorff space (which in particular is normal) but the proof given in the link doesn't show the claim to be true for a normal space and thus not necessarily true for every metric space.
Obviously not every metric space is compact Hausdorff (it is Hausdorff of course).
Regarding your example, I'm not sure I get why are the sets you suggested closed in $\left(-1,1\right)^{2}$?

Comment: @Serpahimz $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a *compact* metric space.

Comment: @DanielRust Oh my goodness, I missed the condition that the $Y_i$ be closed. I'm editing a new example into my answer now.

Comment: @Neal: Indeed, already corrected myself. $\left[-1,1\right]^{2}$ however is compact Hausdorff so Martin's original counter example was incorrect. Regarding $\left(-1,1\right)^{2}$ like I mentioned in my previous comment I don't immediately see why the sets Martin suggested are closed in $\left(-1,1\right)^{2}$.

Comment: @Serpahimz They are the intersection of the closed sets $\mathbb{R}^2 - (\mbox{fattened interval}_i)$ with the space $(-1,1)^2$, so they are closed in the subspace topology.

Comment: @Serpahimz: yes, my first example was incorrect (I missed that the intersection still contains $\{-1\} \times [-1,1]$ and $\{1\} \times [-1,1]$.) // The second sets are closed since I remove open sets from $(-1,1)^2$

Comment: Neal's new answer and Martin's revised example look to both work fine to me.