# A compact Hausdorff space $X$ is finite if and only if $C(X)$ is finite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Assume that the vector space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ is finite-dimensional. I would like to conclude that $X$ is ﬁnite.

Certainly, the converse implication is trivial.

Comment: For each $x \in X$, consider the linear map that sends $f$ to $f (x)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Is the map 1-1 or onto?

Comment: It's definitely not $1-1$. @jaggu

Comment: Is it onto?@ThomasAndrews

Comment: Sure, for any $r\in\mathbb R$, you can define the constant function $f_r:X\to \mathbb R$ so that $f_r(x)=r$.  However, I don't think knowing if this map is "onto" is the key here. @jaggu

Answer (score 4):

By contraposition, suppose that $X$ is infinite. By the Hausdorff property, one may construct recursively a countably infinite family $(O_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of pair-wise disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $X$. For each $n$ pick $x_n\in O_n$. [As $X$ is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329866/compact-hausdorff-spaces-are-normal), by Urysohn's lemma, for each $n$ there exists a continuous function $f_n$ such that $f_n(x_n)=1$ and $$\{x\in X\colon f_n(x)\neq 0\}\subseteq O_n.$$ Clearly, the set $\{f_n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is linearly independent, so $C(X)$ is infinite-dimensional.