# Every subset of a compact Hausdorff space is completely regular

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to convince myself on this statement.

Suppose $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, and let $U\subseteq X$ be any subset. Let $x\in U$ and let $C\subset U$ be closed in the subspace topology with $x\notin C$. Then $C$ is also closed in $X$.

How am I suppose to define a continuous function $f:U\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$ for each $y\in C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since X is compact Hausdorff, it is normal
thus completely regular.  Finally notice that
every subspace of a completely regular space
is completely regular.

Comment: But why does compact and Hausdorff imply normal?

Comment: Compact Hausdorff implies regular. Compact Hausdorff regular implies normal.

Comment: @SidCaroline see answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1329866/4280)