# Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and let $x,y \in X$, and $x \not = y$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Then there is a continuous real-valued function $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x) \not = f(y)$. I'm really stuck upon this problem. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the theorem of Tietze Uryshon, if $X$ is Hausdorff, $\{x,y\}$ is closed, defined $f$ on $\{x,y\}$ by $f(x)=0, f(y)=1$, it can be extended to $X$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem

Answer (score 3):

[Compact Hausdorff spaces are normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329866/compact-hausdorff-spaces-are-normal). Then apply [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma).